# How to create own trust manager in java for apache httpclient library to ignore certificate in apache httpclient 4.2?

Tags: java, web-services, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

Can somebody tell me how can i ignore the ssl certificate during web service call.
I am calling https weburl to get api response but getting peer not authenticated error.
Old examples are not working as some of methods are deprecated so can somebody tell me/ provide some sample code so that i will not get this error.

I just came to know that the problem is coming due to Certificate.
I am using 3rd party API for db calls & they have ssl certificate for their domain
i.e. www.dbprovider.com (SSL certificate is *.dbprovider.com)
& they created subdomain for us which look like myapp.dbprovider.com

So now the problem is no peer certificate is available when i try to hit through command

```
openssl s_client -ssl3 -showcerts -connect myapp.dbprovider.com:443

openssl s_client -tls1 -showcerts -connect myapp.dbprovider.com:443
```

Can somebody tell me what i should now do with it. Is there any control on dbprovider site so that they can provide me some configuration or i have to write code to ignore their certificate (but for ignoring certificate we are not getting their peer certificate)

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom `SSLSocketFactory` as described here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e512. One such factory that ignores self-signed certs is [`EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/contrib/org/apache/commons/httpclient/contrib/ssl/EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory.java?view=markup).

```
  ProtocolSocketFactory factory = new EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory();
  try {
    URI uri = new URI(config.getBaseUrl());
    int port = uri.getPort();
    if (port == -1) {
      port = 443;
    }
    Protocol easyHttps = new Protocol(uri.getScheme(), factory, port);
    hostConfiguration.setHost(uri.getHost(), port, easyHttps);
  } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    throw new IOException("could not parse URI " + config.getBaseUrl(), e);
  }
```

Source: http://frightanic.com/software-development/self-signed-certificates-in-apache-httpclient/